# Java Applet Clear Screen

Tags: java, applet, screen

For Java Applets, what is the best method of "clearing the screen"? Is there a particular function or would you create and paint a white rectangle the size of the screen?

What are the best practices for the purpose of clearing the entire applet screen?

Comment: The whole screen or just a JPanel or some other Component?

Comment: The entire applet. I have a series of drawings, and at each successive time I need to clear the screen and paint the new drawing to the applet screen.

Comment: `super.paintComponent` should work (if you working with a `JComponent`) or `super.paint` for the top level container. You should try and avoid over-ridding the paint method of the top level container, you'll generally get better performance by using a custom component

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually the best practices of clearing applet will be painting background

```
Dimension d = getSize();
g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
g.fillRect(0, 0, d.width, d.height);
```